# prometheus: how prometheus handles the data type overflow?

Tags: prometheus

The prometheus client keeps updating the metric and seems do not consider overflow. For example, the counster `Add()`:

```
func (c *counter) Add(v float64) {
    if v < 0 {
        panic(errors.New("counter cannot decrease in value"))
    }
    ival := uint64(v)
    if float64(ival) == v {
        atomic.AddUint64(&c.valInt, ival)
        return
    }

    for {
        oldBits := atomic.LoadUint64(&c.valBits)
        newBits := math.Float64bits(math.Float64frombits(oldBits) + v)
        if atomic.CompareAndSwapUint64(&c.valBits, oldBits, newBits) {
            return
        }
    }
}
```

The `c.valInt` would overflow and wrapped around from 0.
How prometheus handles this case when it scrapes such rewind metric?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prometheus is designed to handle counter resets like this, the `rate` function has code for it. It more commonly happens when a process restarts.

An overflow is also quite unlikely. Even if you were incrementing by a billion a second it'd take several hundred years to overflow.

Comment: what about the `sum` of `histogram` type? The addition may be arbitrary big value, so it may overflow the `sum` quickly. https://github.com/prometheus/client_golang/blob/master/prometheus/histogram.go#L248

Comment: Similar logic applies, as long as you restart your applications at least once a decade you should be fine.