# Micrometer's Timer with prometheus metric registry, _sum metric value going to 10G and resetting to -10G on the graph, giving incorrect values

Tags: java, prometheus, instrumentation, micrometer

I am using micrometer api in one of my applications and using `Timer` to monitor the metrics related to latency from the upstream. While doing this I have observed that _sum variable is going to the value near to 10G in the graph and falling down close -10G. I am suspecting that this is because overflow of the value.

`public void recordTime(String name, long value, String topic, TimeUnit unit) { Timer timer = topicTimerCache.computeIfAbsent(name+topic,x->Metrics.timer(name,getSplittedTopicTag(topic))); timer.record(value, unit);`
In the below question I have read that prometheus supports
incrementing a billion a second. In my case I am not even hitting that scale.
[prometheus: how prometheus handles the data type overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718206/prometheus-how-prometheus-handles-the-data-type-overflow)

Help me in figuring out the issue. Thanks in Advance.

[max_value_in_graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rR6nA.png)

Comment: What unit is 10G? Gazillion? Gigabytes?  It feels like we are missing something here. Can you include the code for how you are recording the timer value?

Comment: can you open the attached image, it's unit in the graph of prometheus.

Comment: Yes I can see the chart. Can you interpret what 'G' stand for? But I still think is it related to how you are recording the amount so the code is needed.